# Possibility of rendering texture while reading from same

Tags: opengl

I have an FBO with a texture bound. Now I am wondering if I can read from the texture and display it in the same FBO the same texture is bound to.

Is that possible?

Comment: you can render to a buffer and use that as a texture the next frame

Comment: Yes okay, that's one way to do it indeed, but it doesn't really answer it.

Comment: Image load/store in GL4 will allow you to do something to this effect, but naturally it will tremendously increase the complexity of your software. Do you actually have a real use-case for wanting to do this, or is this just a curiosity?

Comment: I can't use GL4 unfortunately. I have a usecase, but I can get around it with an extra FBO indeed. Mostly curious about the most efficient but viable route.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is undefined behavior. The GL spec [(for example 3.3 core)](http://www.opengl.org/registry/doc/glspec33.core.20100311.pdf) has a special section about "feedback loops". Ctiting from section 4.4.3 there, subsection "Rendering Feedback Loops":

> Special precautions need to be taken to avoid attaching a texture image to the
>   currently bound framebuffer while the texture object is currently bound and enabled
>   for texturing. Doing so could lead to the creation of a rendering feedback
>   loop between the writing of pixels by GL rendering operations and the simultaneous
>   reading of those same pixels when used as texels in the currently bound
>   texture. In this scenario, the framebuffer will be considered framebuffer complete
>   (see section 4.4.4), but the values of fragments rendered while in this state will be
>   undefined. The values of texture samples may be undefined as well, as described
>   under “Rendering Feedback Loops” in section 3.8.11

(The spec will go on defining the situation further. For example, it is OK to use the same texture object when reading from a different mipmap leven than rendering into, but the general picture is clear.)

You should be aware that "undefined behavior" includes everything up to the expected behavior. I've seen this where someone had such a feedback loop, and it did work (on his particular system...) for a very simple image filtering operation. But as soon as he added more complex operations, the results got screwed up. So the only advice I can give is: don't try this at home...